# Waht does variable following square brackets mean?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm, addressing-mode

I am trying to use cl.exe to compile my C++ code to asm code:

```
  1  #include <stdio.h>
  2  
  3  int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
  4  {
  5     int x;
  6     printf("Enter X:\n");
  7     scanf("%d", &x);
  8     printf("You enterd %d\n", x);
  9     return 0;
  10  }
```

compiled asm code with line 7:

```
    ; Line 7
    lea eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET $SG5562
    call    _scanf
    add esp, 8
```

what does `_x$[ebp]` mean?

Comment: MSVC will have earlier emitted a line like `_x$ = -8` or something to define that local var name as an assemble-time constant for the position within the stack frame.